# Conjoined twins formation theory

Tags: embryology

is it theoretically possible to take two fertilized mammalian eggs and push them together to make conjoined twins? How about forming non-identical conjoined twins?

Answer (score -1):

The more generally accepted theory for conjoined twins is fission, in which the fertilized egg splits partially. So I don't think that what you said is possible. Not seen this happening before... even the conjoined twins share same placenta indicating they originate from same fertilized egg.